# JUnit checking if the message thrown by an exception is either `stringA` or `stringB`

Tags: java, exception, junit, junit5

In my code I have some pattern like (I tried to simplified as much as possible):

```java
import com.google.common.base.Joiner;
import com.google.common.base.Preconditions;
import java.util.Set;

public void funcSubSet() {
   final Set<String> setA = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "d"));
   final Set<String> setB = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("a"));
   Preconditions.checkArgument(setB.constainsAll(setA),
                               "The strings %s are present in setA but not in setB",
                               Joiner.on(", ").join(setA.stream()
                                                   .filter(Predicate.not(setB::contains))
                                                   .iterator())
                               );
}
```

Basically, this checks if `setA` is fully contained in `setB`. If not, throws an exception and prints the elements that are in `setA` and not be in `setB` (separated by a comma and a space).
When I test it, the problem is that it output the strings not contained in `setB` in different order sometimes and the following test case fails occasionally.

```java
assertThrows(IllegalArgumentException.class,
             () -> funcSubSet()),
             "The strings b, c, d are present in setA but not in setB")
```

Sometime the output is like: "The strings d, b, c are present in setA but not in setB".

How do you I make it agnostic of the order? How can I tell `hasMessage()` or any other assertion that I accept more than one string? I checked and couldn't find anything.

I use JUnit 5!

Answer (score 0):

If you can provide the sets to check from outside in your test (which I would recommend for a good code design and high testability), you can provide a `java.util.LinkedHashSet<E>` instead of a `HashSet` for the test. This class ensure the iteration order to be in the order of first insertion, so you get a predictable outcome.

If you cannot choose the actual `Set` implementation for your test, I would write the test a bit different:

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;

//...

// expect permutation of:
//The strings b, c, d are present in setA but not in setB

Exception thrownException = Assertions.assertThrows(Exception.class, () -> funcSubSet());

String message = thrownException.getMessage();

Assertions.assertEquals("The strings ", message.substring(0, 12), "message start");
Assertions.assertEquals(" are present in setA but not in setB", message.substring(19), "message end");
String variables = message.substring(11,19);
Assertions.assertTrue(variables.contains(" b"), "contains b");
Assertions.assertTrue(variables.contains(" c"), "contains c");
Assertions.assertTrue(variables.contains(" d"), "contains d");
```

With `Assertions.assertThrows` you could also expect a fixed String and work with the caught exception for further details. `org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions` is part of JUnit and does not need 3rd party dependencies like AssertJ.